Truncating a PostgreSQL table using Pyspark
One of my projects requires only updating current rows in an existing PostgreSQL table. I followed the example here, How to truncate a table in PySpark?.
My data is stored by year. I currently have years 2020 - 2024. I only want to update years 2023 and 2024. Total rows is about 2.6M.
I am using Glue 3.0 with Python 3. I inherited this project and am not very fluent with Pyspark. So any help would be appreciated.
Here is my code
input_df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", tableName) \
    .option("user", user) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .load()

    # I filter for the rows I want to keep. This should preserve years 2020-2022                
    input_df = input_df.where(input_df.fiscal_year < 2023)

    write_df = input_df
            
    # save filtered data
    write_df.write.format("jdbc").options(driver="org.postgresql.Driver", url=url, user=user, password=password, dbtable=tableName, truncate='true').mode("overwrite").save()

The problem is that the data is not being replaced in my table. I still have the same records I started with. All 5 years. And I would expect to have only 2020-2022.
